# focus not lost on System.exit

Tags: javafx, focus, changelistener, system.exit

i have some TextFields to perform actions when they lose focus.
I attached a ChangeListener to their focussedProperty and everything works fine .
BUT when i leave the application with System.exit(0) there is no final Change performed .
Here is my Listener :

```
public abstract  class TextUpdateListener implements ChangeListener<Boolean> {

private TextField field ;
private String initialText ;
private StringProperty text ;

    protected TextUpdateListener(TextField field){
        this.field = field ;
        initialText = "";
        text = field.textProperty();

    }
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue,
            Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue == true){
                System.out.println("focus gained");
                initialText = field.getText().trim();
                System.out.println("Text on focus gained : "+text.get());
                System.out.println("InitialText on focus gained : "+initialText);

            }
            if(newValue == false){
                System.out.println("Text on focus lost : "+text.get());
                if(initialText.isEmpty()){
                    if( ! text.get().isEmpty()){
                        onCreated();
                    }

                }
                if(! initialText.isEmpty()){
                    if(text.get().isEmpty()){
                        onDeleted();

                    }
                    else if(! text.get().equals(initialText)){
                        onChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
    }
    public String getInitialText(){
        return initialText ;

    }
    public TextField getField(){
        return field ;

    }
    public abstract void onDeleted();

    public abstract void onChanged();

    public abstract void onCreated();

}
```

I would really appreciate some help !

Answer (score 0):

No new events will be processed once you have called `System.exit(...)` (or `Platform.exit()`).

If there is code you want to run when the application shuts down:

1. Call `Platform.exit()` instead of `System.exit(...)` to exit the application
2. Override the [`stop()` method in your `Application` subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--), and implement the code you need to execute there.